# Connecting to remote server api.interfaces.records.teams.microsoft.com failed with the following error message

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, scripting, microsoft-teams, azure-appservice

I am using this command to connect Microsoft Teams through PowerShell 7.1.3 OR PowerShell 5.1.

Step 1
Connect to first domain (bijay@abc.com)

```
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
$userCredential = Get-Credential
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $userCredential
```

Result: Connected Successfully:
[image]

Step 2
Hit the command to get online application instance of the tenant:
Get-CsOnlineApplicationInstance

Result: Retrieved all the app instances successfully

Step 3
Connect to second domain (bijay@xyz.com) in the same PowerShell

```
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
$userCredential = Get-Credential
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $userCredential
```

Result: Connected successfully

Step 4:
Hit the command to get the application instances again:

```
Get-CsOnlineApplicationInstance
```

Error Result: *Processing data from remote server api.interfaces.records.teams.microsoft.com failed with the following error message:*

[image]
Now in the above steps, if I use Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams command after step 2, I get the expected result.

I am doing all this through C# .Net and Asp.Net Core. SDK: Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK
Code Snippet

```
scriptContents.AppendLine("Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process");
            scriptContents.AppendLine($"$MicrosoftTeamsConnectorPath = Get-Item -Path {microsoftTeamsModulePath}");
            scriptContents.AppendLine("Import-Module $MicrosoftTeamsConnectorPath -verbose");
            scriptContents.AppendLine("Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession");
            scriptContents.AppendLine("Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams");
            scriptContents.AppendLine("$SecureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force");
            scriptContents.AppendLine("$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist 
            $UserName, $SecureStringPassword");
            scriptContents.AppendLine("Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $Credential");
            
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                    ps.AddScript(scriptContents.ToString());
                    ps.AddParameters(scriptParameters);

                    ps.Streams.Error.DataAdded += Error_DataAdded;
                    ps.Streams.Warning.DataAdded += Warning_DataAdded;
                    ps.Streams.Information.DataAdded += Information_DataAdded;

                    var pipelineObjects = await ps.InvokeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                  if (ps.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                    {
                        
                    }
                   else
                    {
                    }
           }
```

Main Concern/Question:
When I run the application script locally, Steps 1 to 4 works fine by using **Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams** but it does not works when I host it on Azure App Service.
Error on Application Insight:
[image]

What is the best way to remove the previous MicosoftTeams session (step 1 to 2) so that step 3 to 4 would work?
Is there anything I am missing?

**Note: I want the PowerShell to work for multiple domains with Microsoft Teams module commands like Get-CsOnlineApllicationInstance when hosted as a .NET core OR .NET framework web API on Azure App Service**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.codetwo.com/kb/troubleshooting-remote-powershell-connections/#old-ps-version

Comment: @BreetLee As you see, the connection works fine for step 1 and step 2. When I logged into another domain from abc.com to xyz.com, its creating the error while getting application instances. I think this should be related to session problem in powershell. And if I use Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams between step 2 and step 3, it works fine locally but not in Azure app service.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Bijay to achieve your requirement either we have to run connecting second domain in another window or create separate instances in azure app service. New-PSSession to explicitly create a new session, which can then be utilized by passing the session to the -Session parameter of Invoke-Command, Enter-PSSession, and numerous other Remoting-aware commands.  https://devops-collective-inc.gitbook.io/secrets-of-powershell-remoting/session-management

For running in azure app service create multiple instances. https://medium.com/devoops-and-universe/microsoft-azure-multi-instance-infrastructure-with-appservice-as-the-center-of-the-universe-29db20400eaa